# How to reduce redundant copies with rvalue reference and std::move()

Tags: c++11, move, rvalue-reference

In this code,
How many times would the generated string be copied for each case(case 1 ~ case 4)?
Could anyone confirm my answers in the code body?
If so, can I tell `case 4` is more efficient than `case 1`?
Or any other suggestions?

```
#include <string>


std::string GenerateString() {
  return "very long string";
}


class Message {
 public:
  Message(const std::string &s) : payload_{s} {}
  Message(std::string &&s) : payload_{std::move(s)} {}

 private:
  std::string payload_;
};


int main() {
  // case 1
  const std::string &s1 = GenerateString();  // no copy
  Message msg1{s1};  // copy: s1 -> payload_

  // case 2
  std::string s2 = GenerateString();  // no copy(copy elision)
  Message msg2{s2};  // copy: s2 -> payload_

  // case 3
  std::string s3 = GenerateString();  // no copy(copy elision)
  Message msg3{std::move(s3)};  // no copy

  // case 4
  std::string &&s4 = GenerateString();  // no copy
  Message msg4{std::move(s4)};  // no copy

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, your answers are all right. 
About passing `std::string`, further reading https://abseil.io/tips/117. Consider passing by value directly?

Comment: @Nimrod : Thank you for the confirmation and the advice! About 'passing by value directly', I understand it but I'm not prepared to accept it yet.. I'm afraid someday I would make a mistake with it.